# Swift UITest handle starting of all tests and finishing of all test cases

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest, uitest

When writing UITest with XCTest I want to handle of "Starting of all tests" and "Finishing of all test". I want to "Register" user before the test cases and delete account after all test case.I can not use a counter value integer because after all test case its resets. How could I handle this "Start-Finish" ?

Comment: If my answer was helpful would you please accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all described in the Apple documentation. You wanna use setUp and tearDown specifically.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/understanding_setup_and_teardown_for_test_methods

```
class SetUpAndTearDownExampleTestCase: XCTestCase {

    override class func setUp() { // 1.
        super.setUp()
        // This is the setUp() class method.
        // It is called before the first test method begins.
        // Set up any overall initial state here.
    }

    override func setUp() { // 2.
        super.setUp()
        // This is the setUp() instance method.
        // It is called before each test method begins.
        // Set up any per-test state here.
    }

    func testMethod1() { // 3.
        // This is the first test method.
        // Your testing code goes here.
        addTeardownBlock { // 4.
            // Called when testMethod1() ends.
        }
    }

    func testMethod2() { // 5.
        // This is the second test method.
        // Your testing code goes here.
        addTeardownBlock { // 6.
            // Called when testMethod2() ends.
        }
        addTeardownBlock { // 7.
            // Called when testMethod2() ends.
        }
    }

    override func tearDown() { // 8.
        // This is the tearDown() instance method.
        // It is called after each test method completes.
        // Perform any per-test cleanup here.
        super.tearDown()
    }

    override class func tearDown() { // 9.
        // This is the tearDown() class method.
        // It is called after all test methods complete.
        // Perform any overall cleanup here.
        super.tearDown()
    }

}
```